# Replace table names occurence in SQL

Tags: c#, string, winforms, replace

> its not first occurence. after a index i need to get the first
>   occurence. the question which you are pointing to is the first
>   occurence without index

i have a *sql query* which i am trying to modify using `String.Replace` but my code is replacing where ever it finds brands, how to avoid this

```
string tempString = 
  "Select t0.brandid,t0.cold,t0.colm, from brands t0 where brandid=@value";
```

I want to replace brands which is table name between from and before t0 to tempbrands

```
    int tempindex1 = tempString.IndexOf("FROM ");
string tempString1 = tempString.Replace("brands", "tempbrands ");
```

expected result is `Select t0.brandid,t0.cold,t0.colm, from tempbrands t0 where brandid=@value`

Comment: its not first occurence. after a index i need to get the first occurence. the question which you are pointing to is the first occurence without index

Comment: `IndexOf`has an overload to specify the start index, see this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've reopened the question, since it's more about SQL parsing than just first substring finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the previous linked duplicate, i've modified it to specify where to start the search from. I don't know if this is what you were looking for:

```
string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace, string from)
{
     int posFrom= text.ToLower().IndexOf(from.ToLower());
     if (posFrom < 0)
     {
          return text;
     }
     int pos = text.ToLower().IndexOf(search.ToLower(),posFrom);
     if (pos < 0)
     {
          return text;
     }
     return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
}
```

Usage:

```
string tempString1 = ReplaceFirst(tempString, "brands", "tempbrands ", "FROM");
```

**Edit**

To replace the string between two strings you may modify the previous method like the following, but note the using just a letter as a limit is not possible. For example, i you use "t" as a limit as you ask in the comment, if the table name contains a "t" it's not going to work. You'd rather use "t0":

```
string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace, string from, string to)
{

    int posFrom = text.ToLower().IndexOf(from.ToLower());
    if (posFrom < 0)
    {
        return text;
    }
    int posTo = text.ToLower().IndexOf(to.ToLower(),posFrom);
    if (posTo < 0)
    {
        return text;
    }

    int pos = text.ToLower().IndexOf(search.ToLower(), posFrom);
    if (pos < 0 ||pos >posTo)
    {
        return text;
    }
    return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
}
```

Usage:

```
string tempString1 = ReplaceFirst(tempString, "brands", "tempbrands ", "FROM","t0");
```

Comment: Glad to help @Tan :)

Comment: can you please help me replace string between "From" and "t", that is "From tablename t0" if the search lies between "from" and "t" then only replace tablename can you please help me achieve this

Comment: See updated answer, but as i say there you can't use a one letter pattern as a limit, because a match may be produced in the table name

Comment: yes you are right. i am thinking how to overcome this

Comment: There are possible ways, but seems a bit dirty to me. You could set the limit in the second space after from or things like that..it depends on your prossible cases

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you want to change the *1st occurence* only; it's more likely that you want to *rename table* within SQL. e.g. for (`brands` => `tempbrands` change):

```
  select b1.brandId,
         b2.brandId
    from brands b1, -- both tables should be changed: this
         brands b2  -- ... and this 
   where b1.brandId > b2.brandId and
         b1.colm = b2.colm
```

you may mant change table names within, say, `select` as well

```
  select brands.brandId -- <- all these three occurences should be changed: this,
         brands.colm    --  ... this
    from brands         --  ... and this
```

A *partial* solution (complete solution for arbitrary query wants *SQL parser*) can be implemented by *regular expression*:

```
  String tempString = 
    "Select t0.brandid,t0.cold,t0.colm, from brands t0 where brandid=@value";

  // let's change just whole words "brands" into "tempbrands"
  String sql = Regex.Replace(tempString, 
                             @"\bbrands\b", 
                             match => "tempbrands",
                             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Why the solution is only a *partial* one? SQL is *reacher* language than is's usually expected:

```
  select /*this brands should be left intact*/
         MyField as 'another brands should be spared',
    from "this strange brands table should be skipped"
```

Comment: i am dynamically building query based on user inputs and binding it to datagridview, so that they can export the datagridview data to excel. as the number of selected columns may change resulting in change of keyword "from" i want to find the first occurence of table name (brands here) after "from" and chagne it so my query will produce desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simply..

```
string tempString = 
  "Select t0.brandid,t0.cold,t0.colm, from brands t0 where brandid=@value";
tempString = tempString.Replace("from brands", "tempbrands");
```

Comment: the string query is not constant, it will be dynamically changing. so i need to get the first occurence after from and change it. this is for the fixed value solution